# Early 90s(ish) Sci Fi movie with morphing alien

Tags: story-identification, movie

I've been trying to remember a movie I saw when I was very young for a few months now, but haven't been able to find anything based on what few details I remember. Here's what I do definitely know:

- I was no older than six when I saw it, so I watched it in 1995 at the latest.
- I watched it at home meaning it would have been rented from a video store, so it's likely to have been made at least a few years before I saw it.
- It was set on earth, rather than on another planet or in space.
- There was an alien villain which would, when angry, morph from human shape into its alien form. I can't be definite but I want to say that part of the morphing involved him/his skin turning inside out. One of these transformations was triggered when he was hit in the groin.

I had thought it may have starred Tim Allen, which in turn led me to Galaxy Quest, but that doesn't fit. Unfortunately I can't be definite about any other details that I may think I remember; I've seen a lot of science fiction movies in the eighteen years since so there's probably a lot of merging aspects of several of them. However, I'm hoping that the details I do definitely recall will result in somebody else remembering it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm pretty certain that this is [Suburban Commando](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suburban_Commando) starring Hulk Hogan and Christopher Lloyd and released in 1991.

[image: Suburban Commando Poster]

Hulk Hogan is a warrior who crashes on Earth and ends up living with Lloyd's family. Of course, hilarity ensues.

The villain is General Suitor who is, of course, disguised as a human - but when he gets angry, turns into a creature that looks an awful lot like The Creature From The Black Lagoon.

I don't recall the specific scene (probably tried to block it out), but someone in [this thread](http://www.i-mockery.com/forum/showthread.php?p=766582) mentions a scene similar to the one you recall.

> Suburban Commando:  when Gen. Suitor gets sucker punched in the balls, he turns into something of cross between the Creature from the Black Lagoon and Predator.

[image: General Suitor - alien form]

Comment: That's it, thank you. This has been bugging me for a while and now I don't have to worry about it any more.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like Guyver.
[Guyver WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Guyver)

Other than that, more details could be given, enemies, etc...